# jQuery Keyboard Function keyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

[I have the following HTML/CSS to create a simple keyboard.](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/AHPaY/2/) I have tried experimenting with jQuery keyPress(), yet I can't seem to get it so while you are pressing a key on the keyboard, the corresponding letter has the class 'trigger'.

For example, when you press Q in the textarea with id 'input', the span with id 'q' should change its background to the color green (to the class 'trigger')

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT

So far I have some Javascript, that alerts on each keystroke. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/AHPaY/3/)

Comment: Your fiddle does not have any JavaScript code. Can you provide your real attempts, and tell us where you're stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the background to change only while the key is down you need to set it on `keydown` and set it back on `keyup`:

```
$(function () {
  $("#input").keydown(function (event) {
      $("#" + String.fromCharCode(event.which)).addClass("trigger");
  }).keyup(function (event) {
      $("#" + String.fromCharCode(event.which)).removeClass("trigger");
  });
});
```

Note that `keydown` and `keyup` return key codes not character codes, but as far as the alphabet keys go it is safe to treat them as if they were character codes for the uppercase letters. (So in the following demo I've changed the ids of the spans to be uppercase to save doing arithmetic in the event handlers.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AHPaY/6/

P.S. If you experiment with the demo you'll see this works for simultaneous keypresses too, e.g., hold down Q and T at the same time...

Comment: **Warning**: The absence of a check in this method will generate loads of script errors for most non-alpanumeric characters.

Comment: Yes, what @RobW said is more or less true - it won't give an error for _most_ non-alpha characters because most will still generate a potentially valid element id that will simply not match any elements - and jQuery is fine with that, no errors - but there are keys that will give errors including shift, ctrl, tab, etc.

Comment: Pressing `Enter` will already cause an error. A simple check, eg. with a RegEx as shown below will fix the issue. Another note: The OPs code currently works fine. However, when numbers should also be implemented, a prefix has to be chosen, because IDs may not start with a number. A safer solution is to use a prefix + char codes as IDs, so that invalid characters can also be used.

Comment: @RobW - As I understand it html5 ids can start with numbers. But I'd probably go with your prefix plan anyway. The biggest problem isn't preventing JS errors, since as you say a simple test can fix that, the biggest problem is dealing with the fact that keyup and keydown return key codes rather than character codes and key codes for the non alpha keys aren't consistent across all browsers and operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

On the `keypress` event, the [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property maps to a character code. The [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method can be used to convert the numeric charcode to a character.

In the example, a regular expression is used to check whether the single character is a valid code. If yes, then a class is added.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AHPaY/4/

```
$(function () {
  $("#input").keypress(function (event) {
      $('.trigger').removeClass('trigger');
      var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
      if (/[qwerty]/.test(char)) {
          $('#'+char).addClass('trigger')
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $("#input").keypress(function (event) {
        var keycode=event.which || event.keycode;
        var key=String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();
        $('span.trigger').removeClass('trigger').addClass('key'); // reset  
        $("#"+key).removeClass('key').addClass('trigger'); 
    });
});
```

[**A fiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHPaY/7/).

[**Another fiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ySsQy/1/).

**If you want to leave all the spans green then disable the line commented with reset.**